# Search through multiple tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table Product and Classification and a join table Product_Classification. I wrote a query to search through the tables. One thing I notice is that If I have a product record (or Classification) that is not mapped to Classification the query will not return anything. How can I change my query in a such a way that it does ALSO return a Product that is not mapped a Classification (and a Classification data that is not mapped to a product).

```
$query = "Select *   from $dbname.Product P INNER JOIN Product_Classification PC ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID INNER JOIN Classification C ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID ";
```

EDIT: I do have a Where condition, which is an array of fields

Comment: use left join in your query

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) Sample data and desired results; (2) A more complete query.

Comment: `left join` will allow NULL values in the *right* table (in `from left_table left join right_table`) I guess `outer join` could provide what you want.

Comment: So the left join will partially solve the problem. What about when the left table has null values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql how to emulate a full join

Comment: This is a snap shot of a very big project so I'm unsure about how I'm going to provide 'meaningful' sample data, I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how to do a FULL JOIN between the 3 tables

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks @Terminus

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
$query = "Select *   from $dbname.Product P LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID LEFT JOIN Classification C ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID ";
```

If you want to see more about joins, this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715847/6098214

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
Select *   from $dbname.Product P INNER JOIN Product_Classification PC ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID LEFT JOIN Classification C ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID
```